# Comparative of Equality meaning the same as Comparative of Majority

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, comparative

In my mother language (Portuguese) , these sentences:

> The house looks twice **as** big **as** it  did in the street.
>
> I'll go **as** quickly **as** I can

They mean, when they are translated, this:

> The house looks **bigger** than it did in the street
>
> I'll go **faster** that I can.

Are those sentences equal in meaning? Because, comparative of equality means that the two itens are equal, not more than the other.

Or,  maybe those 2 sentences (using Comparative of Equality)ate  just an exception and I can use both of these structures to say the same thing (One this is more than the other).

Comment: You're ignoring the crucial word "twice". "Twice as X as Y" means something very different from "as X as Y".

Comment: I didn't understand you comment that much. Could you explain a little bit further?  Because, in my first example, I used the word "twice". I would like to know if I can use either comparative of equality or superiority to say the same thing in these cases.

Comment: See Michael Paul's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that the second sentence translates to “faster”, because “as fast as I can” means at my maximum speed. The first sentence uses the word twice, as pointed out by Colin Fine, so it is also a “Comparative of Equality” as you call it, but it compares the original size to double the size. So actually the first translation is also not accurate: 
a = 2b does not mean the same thing as 
a > b

In other words: a sentence with the structure

> A is as B as C

always means: B is equal for A and C

But beware of optional modifiers like twice, half, n times. These can be between is and as, like for example:

> A is 7.3 times as rich as C

which means exactly this: 
The wealth (richness) of A is exactly 7.3 times the wealth of C.

Edit: I've thought of more modifiers: "at least", "at most", "nearly",  "hardly", "likely", "certainly", “not” and I'm sure many adverbs would be able to fill this spot depending on context. Example:

> A is at least as good as B for the job.

Meaning A is equally good or better, compared to B, analogous to ≥

Not all of these have obvious counterparts in mathematical notation, I wouldn’t know how to write “nearly”, but the starting point is always equality.